# How can I find route between two points over pgrouting?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, pgrouting, osm2pgrouting

I have imported osm file to postgresql with this table schema(under question). I used osm2pgrouting tool to create this. How can I find route between two points (for example between NY and Detroid). I need result like this:`53.038683 5.671214,53.038580 5.671132,53.038585 5.671056,53.038573 5.670949,...` array of coordinates. Any ideas pls? As GIS I'm using geoserver.

Table schema:

```
osm_node:
   -node_id
   -osm_id
   -lon
   -lat
   -numofuse
   -the_geom

osm_relations:
   -relation_id
   -type_id
   -class_id
   -name

osm_way_classes
   -class_id
   -type_id
   -name
   -priority
   -default_max_speed

osm_way_tags
   -class_id
   -way_id

osm_way_types
   -type_id
   -name

pointcloud_formats
   -pcid
   -srid
   -schema

relation_ways
   -relation_id
   -way_id
   -type

spatial_ref_sys
   -srid
   -auth_name
   -auth_srid
   -srtext
   -proj4text

ways
   -gid
   -class_id
   -length
   -length_m
   -name
   -source
   -target
   -x1
   -y1
   -x2
   -y2
   -cost
   -reverse_cost
   -cost_s
   -reverse_cost_s
   -rule
   -one_way
   -maxspeed_foward
   -maxspeed_backward
   -osm_id
   -source_osm
   -target_osm
   -priority
   -the_geom

ways_vertices_pgr
   -id
   -osm_id
   -cnt
   -cnt
   -chk
   -ein
   -eout
   -lon
   -lat
   -the_geom
```

Comment: Read http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.3/en/doc/src/tutorial/index.html or http://workshop.pgrouting.org/2.1.0-dev/en/index.html. If you get stuck, come back, but they have clear examples of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how-to by Anita Graser (who goes by the name of Underdark here): https://anitagraser.com/2011/02/07/a-beginners-guide-to-pgrouting/.  In this tutorial you will learn how to use pgrouting with a postgis database based on OSM data.

Comment: The links I posted in the comments are much more up to date and complete.